# How to include an ng-template element without a condition in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if, ng-template

I need an HTML fragment more than once in my Angular template. Instead of writing the HTML code multiple times, I decided to put it inside an **ng-template** element and use that element replicated in the code.

For example:

```
<ng-template #myTemplate>
  <h1>Some Header</h1>
  <p>Some text...</p>
</ng-template>
```

How can I now include this **ng-template** element somewhere in the template?

I know, that this is possible by using an **ngIf** statement, like so:

```
<div *ngIf="false; else myTemplate"></div>
```

However, this feels like a dirty hack to me. Is there another possibility?

Comment: It's not a dirty hack, it's in the Angular documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: @filipbarak what he means is, that it feels like a dirty hack to do it with "false; else..." - and that IS a dirty hack. the official answer can be found below.

Comment: @PatrickKelleter yes, that's the point

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
  <ng-template #myTemplate>
      <h1>Some Header</h1>
      <p>Some text...</p>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate">
  </ng-container>
```

We can definitely use  '**ng-container'** to instantiate the '**myTemplate**' template on the page.

We are referring to the '**myTemplate**' template via its template reference #myTemplate, and we are using the ngTemplateOutlet structural directive to render the template.

**ngTemplateOutlet**  directive inserts an embedded view from a prepared TemplateRef.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. Doing it with an ngIf and a hardcoded "false" value is not the right way to go here. What you are looking for is the NgTemplateOutlet directive:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet